# de-activating the tabs css from jquery-ui.css

Tags: css, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs

I am using Jquery UI, and I need the jquery-ui.css for datepicker and buttonset. However, I am also using jquery tabs in the site.

I have added custom styling to the tabs in my own css folder (not jquery-ui.css), but when I add the jquery-ui.css it adds lots of other styling to my tabs, which look really bad.

I was wondering is there a way to remove the tabs styling from jquery-ui.css?

If it helps this is the html and styling for my tabs:

```
<ul id="product_tabs_list"><li><a href="#description">Description</a></li><li><a href="#features">Features</a></li><li><a href="#specifications">Specifications</a></li><li><a href="#technical">Technical</a></li><div class="clr"></div></ul>


   #product_tabs_list{
-webkit-border-radius: 5px;
-moz-border-radius: 5px;
border-radius: 5px;
margin-bottom: 10px;
padding: 11px 5px;
text-align: center;
   }

   #product_tabs_list li {
float: left;
   }

   #product_tabs_list li a {
background: #fff; 
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 bottom, from(#fff), to(#eaeaea)) no-repeat; 
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#fff, #eaeaea) no-repeat; 
background: -moz-linear-gradient(#fff, #eaeaea) no-repeat; 
background: -ms-linear-gradient(#fff, #eaeaea) no-repeat; 
background: -o-linear-gradient(#fff, #eaeaea) no-repeat; 
background: linear-gradient(#fff, #eaeaea) no-repeat; 
border: 1px solid #cfcfcf; 
color: #3463a0;
font-weight: bold;
padding: 10px 20px; 
-webkit-text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #fff;
-moz-text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #fff;
text-shadow: 0px 1px 1px #fff;
   }

   #product_tabs_list li a:hover {
background: #fff;
   }

    #product_tabs_list li.ui-tabs-active a {
background: #3463a0; 
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 bottom, from(#3463a0), to(#233f64)) no-repeat; 
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#3463a0, #233f64) no-repeat; 
background: -moz-linear-gradient(#3463a0, #233f64) no-repeat; 
background: -ms-linear-gradient(#3463a0, #233f64) no-repeat; 
background: -o-linear-gradient(#3463a0, #233f64) no-repeat; 
background: linear-gradient(#3463a0, #233f64) no-repeat; 
color: #fff; 
-webkit-text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #00204b;
-moz-text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #00204b;
text-shadow: 0px 1px 1px #00204b;
   }
```

Comment: http://jqueryui.com/download/  The jquery ui download page lets you build a custom package.  You can select which elements to include.

Comment: That's for the js file, I am talking about the css file

Comment: @Rooster is right. When you just select datepicker and button on the custom download page you'll notice that the shipped `css` file only contains the css rules for the datepicker and the buttonset (and some other stuff like icons) but there is no CSS for e.g. tabs.

Comment: It still styled the tabs <UL> background. I think I have to manually edit the jquery css, how do I edit tabs for that?

Comment: Tried setting styles to display:none;?